# noob's questions on using jquery mobile

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-mobile, velocity

Before i start must explain that I'm relatively a noob with less experience in web development. A certain site that I'm developing requires and swipeleft and swiperight functionalities for touch based devices namely iphone, ipad, android phones and tablets. To implement this i was suggested to use jQuery mobile and it sounded good as I'm a fan of jQuery.
However despite all google could give me, I'd request clarification on the following

1. Does the doctype compulsorily need to be html 5 as it uses
   attributes like data-role
2. My site uses jQuery and jQueryUI heavily and will jQuery mobile
   distort the actual design layout implemented.
3. I can't seperate view layer for mobile and regular traffic.
4. If jQuery mobile is good for mobile based usage without
       affecting normal design and functionality what will be the best
   ways
       of testing the site for multiple touch based devices (simulators
       maybe).

Some details in simple english from this great place would be wonderful...
Thanks in advance!

## EDIT

To further dig into my problem will a jQuery plugin for swipe functionality like touchSwipe or wipeTouch help me here.
 Also what would best methods to test the functionality from an iPad or an android phone provided I've implemented the plugin with my code. Say some plugin just like IE simulator for firefox that could recognize swipe gesture through mouse drags (Just greedy and desperate)

Thanks again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to separate views for desktop/mobile, I've seen recommendations here for http://detectmobilebrowser.com/ but I haven't used it. That provides code for doing it server-side in various languages or in JavaScript.

One of the main purposes of jQuery Mobile is to provide mobile-specific UI; so the styles will definitely conflict in all sorts of ways with your current templates if you try to just throw both stylesheets in there. If you just want to add swipe support on top of your current site then there are probably lots of jQuery plugins that could help with that.

Re: HTML5, From the jQM docs,

> A jQuery Mobile site must start with an HTML5 'doctype' to take full
>   advantage of all of the framework's features. (Older devices with
>   browsers that don't understand HTML5 will safely ignore the 'doctype'
>   and various custom attributes.)

Comment: thanks for the reply @RwwL and @ Peppered Lemons ...my trouble is I can't seperate views for desktop and mobile...totally out of my scope..will be sure to check out the link and ripple for the future... would a jQuery plugin for swipe functionality alone help me through most of mobile based devices?? right now i don't have the exact targe audience list but I can assume its gonna be primarily for iOS based and android based phones and tablets... and yes, my design did get messed up while trying to couple it with my HTML and custom scripting in Firefox....IE not to be mentioned...

Comment: Sorry, I missed this comment; been off SO for a few days. Sounds like there's a pretty good chance that just a swipe-functionality plugin might be all you need for what you want. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: almost there...close yet so far... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917746/unable-to-get-swipe-direction-and-distance-using-touchswipe-plugin-in-android-or)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery mobile is OK for web apps, but after doing more then on application in JQuery Mobile I would recommend against it for now. There are a lot of phones that do not fully support JQuery Mobile and you will run into issues with many of the methods, and the page layout in general. Most Blackberries, and many HTC phones do not support JQuery Mobile, as well as many other phones.

Detecting if you are on a desktop/mobile is pretty easy. Just look for a `user agent` on page load, and redirect accordingly. If you want I can give you a few ways to redirect based on user agents.

JQuery Mobile may distort the design that you currently have, if you do not format your page correctly. JQuery Mobile will add a lot of extra css, and working around this may prove to be challenging, especially with other JQuery elements. Dialogs are one example of something that JQuery Mobile will do differently from JQuery

The best way would be to test through emulators. Google Chorme has a `Ripple` add on that I tend to use, though it is not the most reliable. Because there are so many different phones, sometimes it is just easier to try to test on as many live ones as you can (different versions, platforms, ect may behave drastically different from each other with JQuery Mobile)