# unable to get swipe direction and distance using touchswipe plugin in android or iPad

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, mobile

Using a jQuery plugin named touchswipe ( [Touchswipe](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/) http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/ ) for a website primarily for desktops and some mobile devices like galaxy tab or iPad for left and right swipe of the third column in the page.
Link to my page made with html and jQuery is as follows:
[my page](http://sampleidg.pcriot.com/simplifiedAgain/html/touchswipe%20swipe%20status%20to%20check%20direction.html)
However while the events for swipe is triggered the distance and direction are given as null. The demos in the [Touchswipe ] site seem to work fine with similar code. Kindly help me on this by letting me know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my issue was primarily because of touchswipe1.2.4 .... the demo was on touchswipe1.2.3 so changing to the older version did the trick....hope this helps some1..